# WiFi disconnecting and wireless adapter disappears

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, connection

I bought an HTPC based on the [GA-E350N WIN 8](http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4461) and using a [TL-WN723N](http://www.tp-link.us/products/details/?categoryid=243&model=TL-WN723N) for WiFi.

From day 1 I started to have problems with the computer losing WiFi connection and the yellow exclamation mark appearing or the TL USB adapter disappearing from the network adapters. To fix the problem I have to unplug and plug the adapter again. This happened both in Windows 7 x64 and Windows 8.1 x64.

It's definitely a problem with the computer since I've tried the wifi adapter in other computers and it worked just fine.

I already unchecked the "Allow the computer to turn off this device" and also disable USB selective suspend.

What could it be?

Comment: Have you installed the [TL-WN723N driver](http://www.tp-link.us/support/download/?model=TL-WN723N&version=V3#tbl_a) ?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, of course.

Comment: "day 1" - is this a new computer? If so, use the warranty.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to use it but I can't think of a hardware fault causing this kind of behaviour.

Comment: What is the error message when you hover over / click the yellow exclamation mark? That will tell us more about the problem(s) you are experiencing.

Comment: Have you checked the USB socket for damage/dirt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this could be due to your laptops power saving mode settings.

- Head to Control Panel
- Power Options
- Click on "Change Plan Settings" (On the power save mode you're using)
- Click on "Change Advanced Power Settings"
- Wireless Adapter Settings
- Select both 'Battery' and 'Plugged In' to "Maximum Performance"

Comment: Didn't realise that you're not using a Laptop! Sorry! Although try this anyway. You may still have the power save mode for wireless enabled.